# Objects are moved when file is re opened

Tags: error

When I save my model and reopen it, I discover that many objects have been displaced and moved to the origin.

However when I recover an autosaved backup file just before the save, objects are where they should be.

This is what my file looks like before saving - (or recovering an autosaved backup) which is the correct arrangement of objects
[image: before save]

And this is what it looks like after opening the saved file. 
[image: opened after save]

When I File > Open an autosaved blend file, objects are relocated to the origin.  The same file accessed by Recover AutoSave opens with objects located as last edited.

As a workaround I can continue to open the autobackup and ignore explicitly saving my file but this can't be normal!

It's a messy file and I'm learning by remodelling a sketchup dxf import. File can be checked out [here](https://www.odrive.com/s/8b26d23c-1024-48d7-814c-5ca1677ad863-5db51250) Save this file with a new name and reopen to reproduce.

Comment: Could it be that you have assigned a key frame to the object that places it at the origin?

Comment: Keyframes are not present for any of the objects - it's a very basic model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve found the reason and a possible solution.

*Reason:*
All of the misbehaving objects are set as children of some weird object.
It probably happened during import.
As you can notice, all of them have location set to zero (0,0,0) without physically being at zero point.
Weird right?

*Solution:*
1) Select all objects through *Select->All*
2) Clear the parent by *Object->Parent->Clear and Keep Transformation*.
This will clear their relationship, but they’ll stay in place.

[image: clear parent and keep transformation]

And you’re done.
All of the objects will be where they’re supposed to be, and they’ll stay there.
You can save the file, reopen, whatever.

*Additional tips:*
1) Check all categories in outliner - its a messy file, and this will help you with orientation.
2) Clean up the file
The file is full of empty text objects and curves.
They were created during import, but now are mostly useless.

*Check all categories in outliner.*
[image: outliner categories visibility]

Hope this helps.
If something ain’t clear, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out.  It has been a usefull learning experience for me (and hopefully others).  I had a feeling the file was screwed up somehow with the import.  At one point Blender crashed without any warning - just disappeared... 

I don't know where all the text objects came from as they were not in the sketchup source. I'll be careful in the future with importing stuff to avoid having a big clean up job. Seems better to model from scratch in Blender!  It's been fun so far.

Comment: It was definitely fun to troubleshoot this problem.

Importing is a messy process

Comment: For information, this didn't solve the problem for me. No matter what I do, I can't seem to move the object.. I even tried to duplicate it, ddelete the original, displace the duplicate. Afer save & reopen, still the same. I only happens with 2 of my objects in the project, and it's not an imported project.

Comment: Hello @elie520 :). If you have another question, please ask it as a separate question with images and perhaps a shared file. This thread is old and you probably won't get an answer :).

Comment: Oh I didn't check the date, thanks for the concern. I ended up deleting the objects and recreating them. It was faster considering what the were.

Answer (score 0):

Select the objects that move when you open the file and enter "remove animation". You may notice that their transforms shown in the "properties" or "N" menu are green. That means they have key frames for animation applied to them. Open the dope sheet, graph editor, or timeline view and make sure you the red dot is not clicked active. If it is when you position objects, it will be adding key frame positions. If you look in your outliner you should also be able to see if there is animation data connected to these objects.

The position you want these objects may still exist on another key frame. move the play head to the frame you want and remove animation from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm not sure where to enter "remove animation"?  

Selecting one of the moved objects and checking its properties in the Transform menu doesn't indicate any changes. 

I've also checked the timeline and can't see any detail that an animation is defined for any of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Graph Editor* and check if there are any keyframes to the object, or simply go to transform option and check if the transform option is highlighted as yellow or green color.

If yes then:

Select your object, go to *Graph Editor* press <kbd>X</kbd> key select *Delete Keyframes*.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - instanced collections were jumping to a new location on file load, but only *sometimes* (using Blender 3.4.1).

The base collection were not parented - each collection is a single mesh object with no parent. I did notice the base collections had a large transform in X and the instanced were jumping by about that distance on load. So I guess somehow the original mesh position was being added to collection instance transforms. But only sometimes, and these objects have been in the scene for several weeks now and only just started to do this.

I tried doing the "clear parent and keep transform" trick, even though the meshes don't have parent. It *seems* to have worked. I've saved and reloaded four or five times and it looks like the instances are not jumping on load now.