# All objects behind the camera dissapeared

Tags: camera

I'm fairly new to blender and mostly use it for quick mock-ups and angles for illustrations. 
I modeled the other week a fairly complete girl room. Took a screen through the camera, saved and then quit. 
Today I revisited the file to grab some of the objects for another scene, only to discover that all objects behind the camera have disappeared.
I checked for backup files and other temps but it seems like the only ones that I have all do the same thing, objects are missing behind the camera.
Tried to unhide, toggled the local view on and off etc. They don't seem to appear in the outliner either. 
Is there anything I can do to recover those objects? 
The blue outline is where my objects were just before saving. :(
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, are the objects not visible, or are they not present in the files at all? Check the *Outliner*.

Comment: @stphnl329 I mentioned in the post, they're not in the outliner either. Outliner is already set to show all scenes too, so they're not present at all it seems.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in the post. Could you have created the objects in another project file perhaps (not referring to the backups/temps)? It sounds like you've already looked thoroughly through those specific files, so that's the only thing that comes to mind.

Comment: The camera placement has no option to make objects disappear. Press Alt+H to unhide objects in object mode. If the objects are missing, it probably means that you deleted them by accident. You can try to go back to previously saved versions. Use File>Recover>Auto_Save. read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156488/objects-are-moved-when-file-is-re-opened and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14413/how-to-setup-auto-save/14463#14463