# Object keeps going back to previous position

Tags: rendering

the object keeps snapping to a particular position in my renders, I open the file after moving and saving my preferred position and find it back in the previous position, please help!

Comment: maybe you've created some keyframes that make it come back to this position? You need to check in the Dope Sheet

Comment: I'm new please how do i check

Comment: what you could do to make sure it's not the problem: select your object, go in the header menu bar > Object > Animation > Clear Keyframes

Comment: if you want to check in the Dope Sheet, open a new window, choose Dope Sheet, look if there's any small yellow dots, they are the keyframes that you may have created for some objects.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Objects are moved when file is re opened](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/156488/78972)

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I created a keyframe unknowingly.